# Problemas com contact form 7 - função on_sent_ok obsoleta

Tags: php, javascript, dom, wordpress

Tenho alguns formulários usando o plugin contact form 7 e cada um redirecionando para uma pagina de sucesso especifica, eu usava o on_sent_ok, entretanto ele não quer funcionar fui verificar e descobri que ele esta obsoleto e o correto agora é utilizar o dom, porém simplesmente não acontece nada ao tentar colocar o dom.

Estou tentando usar o seguinte código, inclui ele no functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    if ( '238' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = 'http://www.site.com.br/sucesso1';
    }else if ( '235' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
    location = 'http://www.site.com.br/sucesso2';
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente substituir wpcf7submit por apenas submit, porque wpcf7submit  não é um evento.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            if ( '238' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
                window.location = 'http://www.site.com.br/sucesso1';
            }else if ( '235' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
                window.location = 'http://www.site.com.br/sucesso2';
            }
        }, false );
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Ainda nada so retorna como se fosse get na url esse parametro site.com.br/#wpcf7-f238-p242-o1

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, se não funcionar eu irei remover minha respotar @Fernando

Comment: não funcionou achei que era por conflito por isso adaptei o codigo, porém ate agora nada

Comment: add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
    <script>
  var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
        $JQuery(document.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
            if ( '238' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
                window.location = 'http://www.site.com.br/sucesso1';
            }else if ( '235' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
                window.location = 'http://www.site.com.br/sucesso2';
            }
        }, false ));
    </script>
<?php
}

Answer (score -1):

wpcf7invalid - Dispara quando um envio do formulário Ajax é concluído com êxito, mas o email não foi enviado porque existem campos com entrada inválida.

wpcf7spam - Dispara quando um envio do formulário Ajax é concluído com êxito, mas o email não foi enviado porque uma possível atividade de spam foi detectada.
wpcf7mailsent - Dispara quando um envio do formulário Ajax é concluído com êxito e o email é enviado.

wpcf7mailfailed - Dispara quando um envio do formulário Ajax foi concluído com êxito, mas falhou no envio de email.

wpcf7submit - Dispara quando um envio do formulário Ajax é concluído com êxito, independentemente de outros incidentes.

fonte: https://contactform7.com/dom-events/